# How to upload Cordova Camera image to Spring MVC?

Tags: angularjs, spring, cordova, spring-mvc, ionic-framework

I'm using Cordova camera to take images and save those images to database.
In server side i am using spring framework and client side i am using angularjs and ionic.

Here my client side code take image

```
$scope.takePicture = function(resp){
         console.log(resp);
         var source;
         if (resp == "camera") {
           source = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
         }else{
           source = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
         };
         var options = {
           quality : 75,
           destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
           sourceType : source,
           allowEdit : true,
           encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
           targetWidth: 300,
           targetHeight: 300,
           popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
           saveToPhotoAlbum: false
         };
          $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
           $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

             $scope.fileImage = imageData;
             alert(' $scope.fileImage' +  $scope.fileImage);
         }, function(err) {
             console.log(err);
         });
          }
```

In save controller i am passing fileImage to formData

```
$scope.saveProduct=function(produce){

var formData=new FormData();
alert('insidde save '+$scope.fileImage);
formData.append("file",$scope.fileImage);
formData.append("produce",new Blob([JSON.stringify(produce)],{type: "application/json"}));
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://192.168.1.10:8080/ABCD_Test/produce',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined},
    data: formData,
        })
```

like this.

but in server side i'm getting null value to file

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/produce" },consumes = {"multipart/form-data"},method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Produce saveProduce(@RequestPart(value="file",required=false)
    MultipartFile file,@RequestPart("produce")Produce produce,
    HttpSession session)throws IOException, SQLException, ParseException {
    System.out.println("I am producing...!");
```

Here MultipartFile file value is null

Comment: instead of  `@RequestPart(value="file",required=false)
    MultipartFile file`   try `@RequestParam(..) MultipartFile file`

Comment: is that your file data `formData.append("file",$scope.fileImage);`

Comment: thank you for your replay. yes my file data is formData.append("file",$scope.fileImage);